# How do you properly taste a beer?

Tags: taste, cicerone

If I want to fully appreciate what a beer is offering, how do I properly taste the beer to reveal all the nuances in the aroma, flavor and aftertaste?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes that the question is broad - there are only a few generally accepted ways of sampling a beer.

Answer (score 14):

[Beer Advocate's Guide](http://beeradvocate.com/beer/101/taste/) is a decent one.  The abridged version is:

1. Look at the beer.  How's the color and head?
2. Swirl it a little bit to pull out the aroma
3. Smell it.  Swirl again if need be.  I recommend taking a 20 second break after smelling, then smelling again, since if you smell too long, your nose gets used to it and it becomes harder to pick up the notes.
4. Sip it.  Don't swallow immediately, but keep it on your tongue for a moment.  Breath out with it still in your mouth and pay attention to the resulting smell (unless you just ate a bunch of garlic before the beer).
5. Taste again as the beer warms up a bit.

Comment: Re: number 3, smelling the back of one's hand is a common method of "cleansing" the olfactory palette to avoid fatigue. It works surprisingly well, IMO!

Answer (score 3):

According to [Oz Clarke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_Clarke), you should burp the beer (to judge the hops).

See this clip from Oz & James Drink to Britain (episode 1, starting at about 2:28):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1FH076U4Lk&t=2m28s

Comment: Totally true. Though this may be frowned upon in many situations.

Comment: Totally agree - never really tried it myself, but the question doesn't really set a context. That said, Fishtoaster's answer is excellent.